# English Language with Euro as Currency

Tags: language-support, date, system-language

I want to use English as my system language but don't want to use the US American date format because it sucks. So I use English UK which comes with pound sterling as currency and a slightly less sucking date format.

I haven't experienced any downsides to this, maybe because I set the currency in LibreOffice to euro manually and no other application seems to use it. The time zone also is CE(S)T and not UTC+0 / UTC+1 as set in the date & time settings, which is good because I live in Germany.

Is there a way to set the language to (US) English, the currency to euro, the date format to the English format with commas (or ideally apostrophes) as thousands separators and a dot as decimal point, and the date format to YYYY-MM-DD (ISO 8601 / EN 28601)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we need to cherry pick. This is what I suggest:

- Open *System Settings* -> *Language Support*
- Make **English (United States)** the top item on the *Language* tab
- Select **English (Ireland)** in the *Regional Formats* tab
- For the date format, add this line to your `~/.profile` file:

  export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8